# Inconsistencia en la lectura de un archivo plano ("?") C#

Tags: c#, sql, archivo

Estoy leyendo un archivo plano de origen de codificación UTF-8 y lo leo con UTF-8, hasta el momento todo funciona bien, pero tengo un registro que por motivos que aun no encuentro me trae un signo de interrogación cuando lo registro en la BD, pero hago todo el seguimiento y no encuentro el motivo.

Archivo de origen (No tienen espacio al final, pero cuando intento borrar la letra E en el archivo plano,debo darle al botón borrar dos veces dos veces, considero que tiene relación con esto)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lectura del archivo en c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el modelo antes de registrar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando registro. El famoso signo de interrogación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta.

Comment: Entiendo que cuando dices UTC-8 te refieres a UTF-8, es asi?

Comment: Ah si, disculpa ya lo corrijo.

Answer (score 1):

Parece obvio que tienes algún tipo de carácter oculto o de control en tu archivo de datos de texto, que hace que aparezca la famosa `?` al almacenarlo en la base de datos.

Un forma de "limpiarlo" es usar el siguiente código, después del `Split` que haces en las tabulaciones:

```
string[] rowData = row.Split('\t');
for (int i=0;i< rowData.Length;i++)
{
     rowData[i] = new string(rowData[i].Where(c => char.IsLetter(c) || char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
}
```

Esta es sólo una de las opciones. Podrías usar expresiones regulares, o filtrar por `!char.IsControl(c)`.